# c# - Compare performance between different types of if null statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have a simple query about performance while checking null in c#.
I have c# code as below. Can anyone explain me which type of statement should i use and why?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int? num = 5;

        string aa = "--------------------";
        if ((num ?? 0) < 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello = ", num);
        }

        string bb = "--------------------";
        if (num is < 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello = ", num);
        }

        string cc = "--------------------";
        if (num is not null && num < 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello = ", num);
        }

        string dd = "--------------------";
        if (num != null && num < 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello = ", num);
        }

        string ee = "--------------------";
    }
}
```

Since, each statement above looks like same but i want to know in terms of performance which should i use and why?
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: [Test it in sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJabgdmQb2XWMwyjgDZMAWdAWQEMBLAOwApyAGAbQF10GAJwDmAZwCUREoSQk56VgBcA/OhYBXALboAvOgCsAbmRT52TgIa70AIgC0Dx0+fObx2WYUAzdGzYbtZVVOcXQAHnQ4ENN5GU95cgBONhsACQBTABtMgHtrGwAaNS1xd3iAXxMPMy50ACM6/Jdm5rcYuSYffy0FUXDI6OrY9s8klIzsvL1C4s1SkeJKpAXzdABjNaaW7Yc2oY6ugN61HMVi7PQAMkvZ/qjJfekVuTG0rNz8ooD5x8Wq+NqwGAWx2LT28U6viOAEI9BoLtdbhF7is4vESK8Jh9pl8SmVPEsVrV0ukQaCXOCSEtykA)     ... still  i would prefer `if (num.HasValue && num.Value < 10) { Console.WriteLine("Hello = ", num.Value); }`

Comment: if num is `null`, I expect `if ((num ?? 0) < 10)` to be true, while `if (num != null && num < 10)` is false. That beeing said, premature optimization is the root of all evil. If you have a performance problem, profile.

Comment: Those string assignments are not doing anything. If you're attempting to create line breaks, a comment would be better: `// --------------------`

Comment: Note that your first condition is different than the others - it returns `true` if `num` is `null`. Another way to check that would be: `if (num.GetValueOrDefault() < 10)` . Just pick the one that is most readable and makes the most logical sense, there will be negligible performance difference between them. Typically we use `if (num.HasValue && num.Value < 10)` for `Nullable<T>` types.

Comment: See [this](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Answer (score 3):

Use whatever is the easiest to read and understand. This is often somewhat correlated with length, so `num is < 10` would be a good candidate.

The time used for things like null-checks would be measured in single digit cycles. So it would be rare for that to matter. You most likely have much more significant performance issues that you should address first. The compiler is also allowed to optimize code as long as the behavior does not change, so it is perfectly possible that there is no performance difference as long as all expressions does the same thing.

Instead of worrying about micro-optimizations like this you should usually start from a much higher level, profile your application and identify areas that are slower than you would expect, and focus your optimization effort on those parts. It is not that uncommon to be able to gain a 10 times speedup by using more efficient algorithms or by avoiding unnecessary or repeated work.

It is somewhat common for inexperienced developers to worry about the wrong things, CPUs are ridiculously fast as long as they get to run well designed low level code. It is much more common for performance issues to be caused by higher level functions that are used without regard of their cost.

Comment: and occasionally performance is damaged by premature optimization, often by causing those who follow to jump through unnecessary hoops.